# Incorrect currency symbol in SKProduct locale

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, currency-formatting

I have a problem when trying to format a price for an in-app purchase. Specifically, I have issues with displaying a Norwegian price using the correct currency symbol ("kr") when using the locale given to me by `SKProduct`.

The current locale ("nb_NO") has the correct currency symbol, "kr". However, the locale given to me by the `SKProduct` ("en_NO@currency=NOK") has "NOK" both as currency code and symbol. In addition to make the price rendering look silly, `NSNumberFormatter` gives a default currency sign (`¤`) unless I specifically set it to something else.

This happens in iOS 6, but on my other test device which has iOS 4.3 it works fine (4.3 SKProduct locale is "nb_NO@currency=NOK").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This miraculously started working by itself a day or two after I posted. I don't know if it was repeated use or some magic fairy discovering my post. I guess all is well that ends well..

Comment: Are you saying that the locale identifier `en_NO@currency=NOK` suddenly started using the "kr" currency symbol - and not NOK??